# DISTANCE expected input to be an agent in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

After a short while I get a typical error message when running my netlogo model:

**DISTANCE expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead.
error while human 18 running DISTANCE**

So far, I was not able to fix the mistake. Netlogo shows me the location in the source code where the mistake occurs:

```
let dist-nearest-resource distance nearest-resource
```

I believe to know that the message means that there are no green patches available to go to. I do know what else to code other than to say that the agents should move on and walk randomly around.

Here, down below is my minimal model to make you better understand. Does somebody know how to fix this?

```
breed [ humans human ]
humans-own [ energy ]

patches-own [ countdown ]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to setup
  ca

create-humans(population)
  [
    set shape "person"
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]

  ask patches [
      set pcolor one-of [green brown]
      ifelse pcolor = green
        [ set countdown 30 ]
        [ set countdown random 30 ]
    ]

  reset-ticks
    end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to go-people
  ask humans [ orientation ]
end

to orientation
   ifelse (energy < 4) [ ;if hungry
     let nearest-resource min-one-of (patches with [pcolor = green] in-cone 3 360 ) [ distance myself ] ;check distance between you and nearest resource (3 fields 360 degrees view)
     let dist-nearest-resource distance nearest-resource ;defines what is the shortest distance
     if is-patch? nearest-resource [ ;if green patch exist at all
       face nearest-resource fd distance nearest-resource ;face it and go directly to it
     ]
   ]
   [ walk ] ;otherwise just walk randomly around
end

to walk
  ask humans [
   rt random-float 30 - random-float 30 ;randomly wandering around
   if patch-at dx 0 = nobody [ ;humans get "bounced" away from the limits of the world
     set heading (- heading) ]
   if patch-at 0 dy = nobody [
     set heading (180 - heading) ]
  ]
end

to sustainability ;countdown on brown patches: if 0 is reached, grow resources again after the time set by user
  if pcolor = brown [
    ifelse countdown <= 0
      [ set pcolor green
        set countdown regrowth-time ] ;exhausted fields need 30 ticks to recover
      [ set countdown countdown - 1 ]
  ]
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to go
  if not any? turtles [ stop ] ;defensive programming

  go-people

  ask patches [ sustainability ]
  set resources count patches with [pcolor = green]

  tick

  if count patches with [pcolor = green] = 0 [ stop ] ;model stops if food is no longer available
  if count turtles = 0 [ stop ] ;model stops if all humans died
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code as it is, you never use the `dist-nearest-resource` variable! Unless you planned to use `dist-nearest-resource` for another purpose, you could just get rid of that whole line.

Furthermore, `face nearest-resource fd distance nearest-resource` (which, by the way, doesn't crash because it's inside your `if is-patch? nearest-resource` condition) could be replaced with a simple `move-to nearest-resource`.

Comment: I like this solution for its clarity! Indeed, after revising my code. I was able to delete the mentioned line. Thank you.

Comment: Oh my, I totally didn't even notice. Nice catch Nicolas!

Answer (score 4):

You're exactly right about what's wrong. `nearest-resource` is `nobody`. Since it is being assigned with:

```
let nearest-resource min-one-of (patches with [pcolor = green] in-cone 3 360 ) [ distance myself ]
```

`patches with [pcolor = green] in-cone 3 360` is empty.

It actually looks like you're trying to handle this already with `if is-patch? nearest-resource` for the next line below the distance check. However, the distance check should be inside the body of the if as well, like so:

```
to orientation
   ifelse (energy < 4) [ ;if hungry
     let nearest-resource min-one-of (patches with [pcolor = green] in-cone 3 360 ) [ distance myself ] ;check distance between you and nearest resource (3 fields 360 degrees view)
     if is-patch? nearest-resource [ ;if green patch exist at all
       let dist-nearest-resource distance nearest-resource ;defines what is the shortest distance
       face nearest-resource fd distance nearest-resource ;face it and go directly to it
     ]
   ]
   [ walk ] ;otherwise just walk randomly around
end
```

However, with this code, the turtle won't do anything if it doesn't find a resource. We can rearrange things so that `walk` is called when it doesn't find anything, like so:

```
to orientation
   let nearest-resource min-one-of (patches with [pcolor = green] in-cone 3 360 ) [ distance myself ]
   ifelse (energy < 4) and is-patch? nearest-resource [ ;if hungry and sees a resource
     let dist-nearest-resource distance nearest-resource ;defines what is the shortest distance
     face nearest-resource fd distance nearest-resource ;face it and go directly to it
   ]
   [ walk ] ;otherwise just walk randomly around
end
```

By the way, `in-cone 3 360` is equivalent to `in-radius 3`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bryan, for your abundant answer. I could optimize my code with your and Nicolas' advises.